# Find items in one list based on items in another list of a different type

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `List<Class1>` and `List<Class2>`, and I'd like get all the items from `List<Class1>` where the item's Id exists in `List<Class2>`, and, conversely, get all the items from `List<Class1>` where the item's Id **does not** exist in `List<Class2>`.

```
public class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AnotherId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AnotherId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I tried several solution with `Contains` but don't find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, the simplest way would be to use the `System.Linq` methods, `Where()`, `All()`, and `Any()`:

```
var matchingIds = list1
    .Where(list1Item => list2.Any(list2Item => list2Item.Id == list1Item.Id))
    .ToList(); 

var nonMatching = list1
    .Where(list1Item => list2.All(list2Item => list2Item.Id != list1Item.Id))
    .ToList();
```

But it's also easy to do with a simple loop:

```
var matchingIds = new List<Class1>();
var nonMatching = new List<Class1>();

foreach (var list1Item in list1)
{
    var foundMatch = false;

    foreach (var list2Item in list2)
    {
        if (list2Item.Id == list1Item.Id)
        {
            foundMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (foundMatch)
    {
        matchingIds.Add(list1Item);
    }
    else
    {
        nonMatching.Add(list1Item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = list1.Where(x => list2.Any(y=>y.Id == x.Id))
                  .ToList();
```

**Even if** both lists contained references to objects of the same type, `Contains` wouldn't work out of the box. Had it been this the case, you would have either implement the interface `IEquatable` for your class or override both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. Only then `Contains` would work as you expected to.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
        foreach(var val in listClass2)
        {
            result.AddRange(listClass1.Where(l => l.id = val.id));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small number of items in your lists, the answer by Christos is the simplest. However, it is an O(n^2) algorithm. If you have a decent number of items in your lists (even in the few thousands), that algorithm will significantly slow down. Let's try an example:

```
    List<Class1> list1 = new List<Class1>();
    List<Class2> list2 = new List<Class2>();

    const int ITEMS_TO_ADD = 30000;

    for (int i=1; i<= ITEMS_TO_ADD; i++)
    {
        list1.Add(new Class1 { Id = i });
        list2.Add(new Class2 { Id = i });
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= ITEMS_TO_ADD; i++)
    {
        list1.Add(new Class1 { Id = -i });
    }

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();                        
    var result = list1.Where(x => list2.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id)).ToList();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

On my machine, that takes around 30 seconds.

A better solution, again, if you have a decent sized data set would be something like this:

```
HashSet<int> list2Keys = new HashSet<int>(list2.Select(x => x.Id));
var resultInList2 = list1.Where(x => list2Keys.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

Which on my machine takes about 10 milliseconds.

Of course, to get items NOT in list 2 you simply change the line to

```
var resultInList2 = list1.Where(x => !list2Keys.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

This is O(n) of course as opposed to O(n^2)